# window.on.scroll event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with firing event.

So the code explains it better:

```
function Test() {
 alert("called");
}


$(window).load(function(){
    $(window).on( "scroll", Test );
});
```

Then I want to fire event for that Test to be called somewhere else.

```
function OnSomeActionDone() {
    $(window).scroll(); // fire event
}
```

But seems like this not work, only from mouse or keyboard scrolling, what is wrong?

Comment: Should it fire from other than mouse or keyboard scrolling?

Comment: Take the line of code that assigned the scroll event hander *out* of `window.load()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not invoking the method correctly.  One way to invoke it programmatically would be to call the `trigger()` jQuery function, passing in the `scroll` handler name, as follows:

```
function OnSomeActionDone() {
    $(window).trigger('scroll'); // fire event
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using it wrong

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   alert('test');
});
```

is like

```
$(window).on('scroll',function() { 
   alert('TEST');
});
```

What you need to do is

```
function OnSomeActionDone() {
    $(window).trigger('scroll'); // fire event
}
```